# Fluent interface with inheritance in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, fluent-interface

I have following fluent interface declaration and class that implements that interface:

```
type
  IDocWriter = interface
    ['{8CB5799A-14B1-4287-92FD-41561B237560}']
    function Open: IDocWriter;
    function Close: IDocWriter;
    function Add(const s: string): IDocWriter;
    function SaveToStream(Stream: TStream): IDocWriter;
  end;

  TDocWriter = class(TInterfacedObject, IDocWriter)
  public
    function Open: IDocWriter;
    function Close: IDocWriter;
    function Add(const s: string): IDocWriter;
    function SaveToStream(Stream: TStream): IDocWriter;
  end;

{ TDocWriter }

function TDocWriter.Open: IDocWriter;
begin
  Result := Self;
  // DoOpen
end;

function TDocWriter.Close: IDocWriter;
begin
  Result := Self;
  // DoClose
end;

function TDocWriter.Add(const s: string): IDocWriter;
begin
  Result := Self;
  // DoAdd
end;

function TDocWriter.SaveToStream(Stream: TStream): IDocWriter;
begin
  Result := Self;
  // DoSaveToStream
end;
```

And I can use above code like this:

```
var
  Stream: TStream;
  ...
  TDocWriter.Create
    .Open
    .Add('abc')
    .Close
    .SaveToStream(Stream);
```

I have to extend above interface by adding `SaveToString` function.

I don't want to add that method to original `IDocWriter` interface because it is not valid method for all interface implementations. So I have done following

```
type
  IStrDocWriter = interface(IDocWriter)
    ['{177A0D1A-156A-4606-B594-E6D20818CE51}']
    function SaveToString: string;
  end;

  TStrDocWriter = class(TDocWriter, IStrDocWriter)
  public
    function SaveToString: string;
  end;

{ TStrDocWriter }

function TStrDocWriter.SaveToString: string;
begin
  Result := 'DoSaveToString';
end;
```

In order to use `IStrDocWriter` interface I have to write code

```
var
  Writer: IDocWriter;
  s: string;

  Writer := TStrDocWriter.Create
    .Open
    .Add('abc')
    .Close;
  s := (Writer as IStrDocWriter).SaveToString;
```

But I would like to be able to use it without the need to declare `Writer` variable, something like following code (which, of course, cannot be compiled)

```
  s := TStrDocWriter.Create
    .Open
    .Add('abc')
    .Close
    .SaveToString;   // Undeclared identifier SaveToString
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Any kind of changes to above interfaces and classes are acceptable (except, obviously, merging those two interfaces into one).

Comment: The entire design looks wrong to me. Fluent is just so bad!

Comment: Pardon my curiousity, but is this interface v. fluent requirement self-inflicted, or does it arise from an actual business requirement and, if so, how?

Comment: @MartynA it is self-inflicted with reason. Interfaces because it is ref-counted and removes need for try..finally blocks. Fluent because it removes the need for declaring variables and makes code more readable when you have longish chain. It can be used inline in otherwise messy code that you can usually have while creating some document or report. Imagine TTextDocWriter, TRichTextDocWriter, TPdfDocWriter, TMetafileDocWriter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
s := (TStrDocWriter.Create
    .Open
    .Add('abc')
    .Close as IStrDocWriter)
    .SaveToString;
```

No, not very nice is it. These two idioms, fluent interfaces and inheritance, simply do not mix.

Comment: Looks nice enough for intended purpose. I am aware that fluent doesn't work with inheritance, but...

Comment: Looks like an excellent example for why we need interface helpers in Delphi.

Comment: @Stefan do you know if there is QC/QP report for interface helpers

Comment: @Dalija No, but according to Marco Cantù they are watching uservoice and there is a request for that: https://delphi.uservoice.com/forums/4433-language-features/suggestions/1345443--class-helper-for-interfaces