# For Delphi 10.2.3: How to create unit.someproperty.anotherproperty.mymethod(myvariable: variabletype): variabletype;?

Tags: function, delphi, components, procedure, delphi-10.2-tokyo

<strike>For Delphi 10.2.3: Not sure how to ask this question, but how do I create a method similar to memo1.lines.add(); and memo1.Lines.Count.ToString; where lines contains many other methods, procedures, and properties??</strike>

This is how I think it maybe:

unit.someproperty.anotherproperty.mymethod(myvariable: variabletype): variabletype;

or

unit.someproperty.unit2.mymethod(myvariable: variabletype): variabletype;

Appearance would appear like:

```
function component.extract.tagA(attribute, source: string): string;
procedure component.insert.tagA(attribute, source, dest: string);
procedure component.modify.tagA(attribute, source, dest: string);
```

if you type component. it would give you help with extract, insert, and modify as options to use next.

<strike>So, how do i make a function or procedure where I can have .extract. or .extract. or .insert. ETC</strike>

<strike>I know this should probably be basic knowledge, but the project I'm working on is becoming big enough for me to make it easier to read and use.  I know this can be done, but I don't know how to word it properly in order to find what I need to do this.</strike>

I want to have multiple units... then I create a component using them so they have nested methods and procedures that work like those DOTTED methods and procedures you see in Tmemo... like memo1.lines.add, memo1.lines.delete, memo1.lines.insert, etc.

Please help!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ignore the memo.lines, or whatever I wrote... for some reason your just reading those words and not really seeing what I'm trying to do.   I'm trying to understand how to create nested methods / procedures... but not nested inside procedures / methods.  When I look up nested procedures in google, i get many examples how to nest inside the procedure, but nothing on showing me how to create a component that has multiple DOTS between words to create a method or procedure!  unit.someproperty.anotherproperty.mymethod(myvariable: variabletype): variabletype;  <<-- create that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi syntax does not permit you to **declare** a class to have dotted sub-properties.

However, you can achieve the effect of this by using a style of coding known
as fluent design (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).  Here is an ultra-simple example:

```
type
  TMySubProperty = class
    protected
    procedure DoSomething;
    property Width : Integer read {define getter and setter}
  end;

  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  [...]
  property
    MySubProperty : TMySubProperty read GetMySubProperty;
  end;

  [...]

  function TMyComponent.GetMySubProperty : TMySubProperty;
  begin
    Result := {calculate the result however you like}
  end;
```

Then, in your code you can write things like

```
  MyComponent.MySubProperty.Width := 666;
  MyComponent.MySubProperty.DoSomething;
```

Obviously you can have any number of sub-properties and they can be nested to any arbitrary
level:  basically, you need a class type for the sub-property and a function in the owning
class (TMyComponent in this simple example) which returns the class instance you are trying
to access.  The `Getter` Functions can be coded to accept parameters which identify a specific
instance of the sub-property class, as in

```
  MyComponent.MySubProperty[i].Width := 666;
```

That should be enough to get you going, if not ask.

Comment: This answers my question.

Comment: Good, I'm glad.  Perhaps you would be so kind as to accept it, then.

Comment: How do I accept it?  I however up voted it.  Never-mind found it... I have to click on the check just below the voting buttons.

Comment: At the top-tleft of the answer is a kind of "Tick" icon.  Just click it ...

Comment: @MartynA Just for the record, your example (while it may be what OP was looking for) has nothing to do with Fluent Interfaces. Main feature of fluent interface is ability to chain method (function) calls without explicitly referencing instance again achieved by returning Self from each call. As example (if you disregard inheritance part of the question, that commonly doesn't mix well with fluent) you can look at [Fluent Interface in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125514/fluent-interface-with-inheritance-in-delphi)

Comment: Yeah, you should really delete the fluid interface reference, as it is not what is happening here and therefore misleading.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is nested objects. `Memo1` is an instance of the `TMemo` class, which has a `Lines` property that is an instance of the `TStrings` class, which has methods like `Add()`, `Delete()`, `Insert()`, etc and properties like `Count`, etc.

So, in your `component`, it would need nested objects for `extract`, `insert`, and `modify`, and those objects would need to be instances of types that have a `tagA()` method.

Comment: This also explains what I'm looking for, but I see you have no example on how.  MartynA shares an example on how I can hopefully achieve it fluent design.  I'm going to go and try to code it now.  Remy, do you have a different example for what your explaining or is it the same?

Comment: I Think what's Remy wants to say is You should understand, that U can have an object as property/class field of another object...

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Fields_(Delphi)